# Ajuda com um MER

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Bom alguém poderia me ajudar com meu MER estou com dúvidas se estou utilizando a logica correta nos relacionamentos e cardinalidades:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> um relatorio pode ter um ou mais serviços
>
> 1 - n
>
> um request tem um ou mais relatorios
>
> relatorio tem apenas um request
>
> um relatorio pode ter um ou mais serviços ( ex no relatorio com ID 1
>   foram utilizados dois serviços) e serviço pode fazer parte de vários
>   relatorios
>
> Um request gera um boletim ( 1:1 )

esses dois relacionamentos estão me confundindo

Comment: Qual a justificativa em seus requisitos para você ter boletim_request como uma entidade a parte já que o relacionamento é 1:1?

Comment: @anonimo no caso toda requisição gera um boletim esse boletim vai conter o relatorio de serviços e de peças

Comment: Mas apenas com os atributos listados em seu modelo continua tendo sentido?

Comment: eu ainda não terminei esse relacionamento ele irá receber mais atributos e fk, minhas dúvida é mais com relação ao meu relacionamento requisição e serviços .

Comment: Uma requisição pode ter 0 ou mais serviços e um serviço pode fazer parte de n requisições.

Comment: Um relacionamento N:N é modelado da maneira como você fez: uma entidade auxiliar representando o relacionamento e dois relacionamentos 1:N (ou 0:N) desta entidade auxiliar com cada uma das entidades originais.

Comment: @anonimo não entendi muito bem, será que você poderia por uma resposta de como eu posso melhorar isso? Tipo eu levei em conta um relacionamento de Vendas / Produtos n:n um ou mais produtos fazem parte da venda e uma venda tem um ou mais produtos e então tem se uma tabela item_venda .

Comment: Tentei aplicar isso nessa situação por ser um relacionamento n:n